# Access Blob Properties in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I need to get the blob properties, in there is a last modified date. I need the date for comparison. Have read a number of articles, and thought it was because I was not using a CloudBlockBlob, but I cannot extract the properties from it.

My code so far returns the names of the blobs:

```
public static void ListBlobsAnonymously()
    {
        //Get the blob from the URL - URL is in the app.config file so it can be changed easily should it need it. 
        CloudBlobContainer container = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VOURL"]));

        //For each of the blobs, write the file name out. This will be needed for a comparison. 
        foreach (IListBlobItem blobItem in container.ListBlobs())
        {
            string name = blobItem.Uri.Segments.Last();
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

This is the structure of the blobs:

```
<EnumerationResults ServiceEndpoint="https://test.blob.core.windows.net/" ContainerName="downloads">
<Blobs>
    <Blob>
        <Name>
        This_is_a_test
        </Name>
        <Properties>
            <Last-Modified>Tue, 01 Oct 2010 14:33:48 GMT</Last-Modified>
            <Content-Length>452</Content-Length>
            <Content-Type>application/zip</Content-Type>
            <BlobType>BlockBlob</BlobType>
        </Properties>
    </Blob>
</Blobs>
</EnumerationResults>
```

It is the last modified within the properties that I need to get hold of and cannot.

Comment: Try     blob.Properties.LastModified

Comment: With the code above, I can only access the properties of the container, not the blob itself, which is the crux of my problem I think. So I can get container.Properties.LastModified, but I really need the blobItem.Properties.LastModified, but I cannot access the properties of the ListBlobs.

Comment: "I can get properties, i need properties, i can not get properties". This is very confusing. Please reframe your comment

Comment: If you look at my code, I am explicitly stating what I can, and cannot get the properties of. I have a container that I CAN get the properties of. I have blobs that I CANNOT get the properties of. It is the blob properties I need to get hold of. Not sure how I can make that more clear?

Comment: What do you exactly want?? Properties? You got it. What is the thing other than properties you want and cannot get

Comment: see if this link helps  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266341/how-can-i-get-references-to-blockblob-objects-from-cloudblobdirectory-listblobs

Comment: Link was great, got it, thanks for your help.

Comment: anyway If @GauravMantri sir sees your question related to Azure, you don't need any link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code: (note: not supported/working on NET Core)

```
        CloudBlobContainer container = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VOURL"]));

        //For each of the blobs, write the file name out. This will be needed for a comparison. 
        foreach (IListBlobItem blobItem in container.ListBlobs())
        {
            var blob = (CloudBlob)blobItem;
            if (blob != null)
            {
                string name = blobItem.Uri.Segments.Last();
                Console.WriteLine(name);
                Console.WriteLine(blob.Properties.LastModified);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Basically you would need to cast `IListBlobItem` to `CloudBlob` and there you will have access to blob's properties.

Comment: That is what I was missing, took a read of the link 'It's a trap' posted which got me onto this track. Thanks for taking the time to reply, appreciate it.

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Please make sure to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Any ideas on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53815887/dynamically-get-the-value-of-azure-blob-property

Comment: ListBlobs is missing on platforms net core so the alternative way could be to use the *Async overloads. However, please note that there is no ListBlobsAsync, because there is no async counterpart of IEnumerable in .NET. So, you should call ListBlobsSegmentedAsync and handle the continuation token that it returns. See question below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26396460/does-not-found-listblob-in-cloudblobcontainer