# Dynamically get the value of Azure blob property

Tags: c#, azure, properties, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Is there a way to get the property of Azure blob dynamically without explicitly mentioning it.

Example, if I want to get the created date of blob then I need to write something like this

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("Storage Account")
CloudBlobClient sourceBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

var sourceContainer = sourceBlobClient.GetContainerReference("Container Name");
var blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("Blob Name");

blockBlob.FetchAttributesAsync().Wait();
var blobCreatedDate = blockBlob.Properties.Created;
```

I am trying to avoid explicitly mentioning "Created" present in the last statement.

Any pointer to get this achieved ? can we loop through the properties of blob ?

Comment: "*can we loop through the properties of blob ?*" `foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property in blobkBlob.Properties.GetType().GetProperties()) { ... }` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to achieve it like this

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("Storage Account")
CloudBlobClient sourceBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

var sourceContainer = sourceBlobClient.GetContainerReference("Container Name");
var blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("Blob Name");

blockBlob.FetchAttributesAsync().Wait();
//var blobCreatedDate = blockBlob.Properties.Created;
var propName = "Created"
Type tModelType = blockBlob.Properties.GetType();
var propertyInfo = tModelType.GetProperty(propName);
If  (propertyInfo != null) {
    var blobCreatedDate = propertyInfo.GetValue(blockBlob.Properties).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Obviously, don't forget `if (propertyInfo != null) { ... }`

Comment: @Cid - Yeah.. got error when I passed wrong property names. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: @Pரதீப் what would be a use case for this approach ?